# Get (echo) all role names assigned to user

Tags: user-roles, array

Im trying to do something which I feel should be quite easy but I can't seem to quite grasp. 
I have the below code which echo's users roles. Great. Fantastic.
BUT I have a problem when a user is assigned to multiple roles. It returns null. 
Can someone please help me?

Thanks

```
global $wp_roles;
$user_role = implode(', ', get_userdata($user->ID)->roles);  
echo($wp_roles->role_names[ $user_role ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need a foreach loop and echo each roles name separately. Here's how to do it:

```
global $wp_roles;
$user_role = get_userdata($user->ID)->roles;

// Check if there is any role for this user
if( $user_role ) {
    foreach ( $user_role as $key => $role ) {
        echo $wp_roles->role_names[ $role ];
        // Add a seperator except for the last name
        if ( count ( $user_role ) != ( $key + 1 ) ) { echo '/'; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats great! Thanks.
I wonder if you could help with a follow up? 
If the user has more than 1 role, how do I include ' / ' as a separator?

Comment: You're welcome! I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: Awesome! Just 1 more ask if I may? How can I exclude the final / from the end? 
Thanks

Comment: But it already does that. I've tried the code and it doesn't print `/` after the last role.

Comment: I thought it was odd that you wouldn't have accounted for that. After your post just now Ive been scratching me head and after clearing my cache (for some reason) its working as you intended. Many thanks again for your help - You're a star!